# Serializable in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I was using `[Serializable]` in MVC Futures with MVC3. Did it make it into MVC4 in another format? I just want to make sure I am doing things right in MVC4 if I have to install the MVC3 Futures package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the Html.Serialize functionality? If so, no, this did not make it into MVC4 you'll still need the 3 package. There's actually very little that made it into MVC4 (excluding the Web API and tooling changes) limited to really async/await and two razor changes, bundling/minification, and slightly better integration.